# how the append method works on html template tag?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

i am trying to add the content present inside of html template tag inside of both div_1 and div_2 but it gets added only inside div_1, whats wrong in my code please evaluate.

- html code

```html
<!DCOTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <template>
      <h2>Grocery Item</h2>
      <ul>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
      </ul>
    </template>
    <div id="main-div" style="display: 1px solid black;"></div>
    <div id="another-div style="display: 1px solid black;"></div>
    
    <script>
      const template = document.querySelector("template");
      const tempBody = document.importNode(template.content, true);
      
      const list = tempBody.querySelectorAll("li");
      for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
         list[i].textContent = "Item - " + ( i + 1 );
      }

      const div = document.getElementById("main-div");
      const div_1 = document.getElementById("another-div");
      
      div.append(tempBody);
      div_1.append(tempBody);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following way:

```html
<template>
  <h2>Grocery Item</h2>
  <ul>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
  </ul>
</template>
<div id="main-div" style="display: 1px solid black;"></div>
<div id="another-div" style="display: 1px solid black;"></div>

<script>
  const template = document.querySelector("template");
  
  //div_1
  let tempBody = document.importNode(template.content, true); // declare with var or let
  updateTemplate(tempBody);
  const div = document.getElementById("main-div");
  const div_1 = document.getElementById("another-div");  
  div.append(tempBody);
  
  //div_2
  tempBody = document.importNode(template.content, true);
  updateTemplate(tempBody);
  div_1.append(tempBody);
  
  //function to populate tempBody
  function updateTemplate(tempBody){
    const list = tempBody.querySelectorAll("li");
    for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
     list[i].textContent = "Item - " + ( i + 1 );
    }
  }
</script>
```